# C: weird printf behaviour

Tags: c, printf

I'm learning C at the moment and decided to experiment a little with pointers. I compile and execute the following code:

```
int main()
{
    float a = 8;
    int *b, *c;
    b = &a;
    c = &b;
    printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n", a, b, c);

    exit(0);
}
```

Executing the code gives:

```
-562800092
-562800104
0
```

Now, I know I'm trying to print a float as an integer. When I print it out using a float, I get the desired result (a float and 2 memory addresses).

If I print it (incorrectly) as an integer, it seems to print a memory address as a. b is printed as another memory address (which is correct, since it's a's address) and c is 0 for some reason. It looks like printf is actually changing some data, somehow.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

I'm using GCC as a compiler btw.

Comment: If you print the data "incorrectly" it will be incorrect. End of story!

Comment: How many warnings were there ? and how many you've ignored ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ints, floats and pointers are not necessarily the same size on the stack. As %d expects an int, it just takes as many bytes as there are in an int from the stack, so you won't necessessarily print what you expect to print if the expected sizes of the items in your format string don't match the sizes of the arguments you provide to printf.

Comment: That could be it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The type of pointer should be `float*` instead of `int*`.

If you want to point a address, use `%p`.

So, the resulting program are:

```
float a = 8;
float *b, *c;
b = &a;
c = &b;
printf("%f\n%p\n%p\n", a, b, c);

exit(0);
```

It outputs:

```
8.000000
e0c70eb4
e0c70eb8
```

Is this what you want? ( You can print out `*b` and `*(float*)(*c)`, both should be `8.0` )

Comment: The correct format specifier for pointers is `%p`, not `%x`.

Comment: @YuHao Thank very much! Edited.

Comment: That's not really what I was after, I believe. I'm not looking for the correct way of printing it, I'm wondering why printf seems to change the other two things I want to print, when I give a wrong type to the first one. Even if I use float *b, *c and the %x, c is still printed as 0, although it should be a pointer to b.

Comment: Although when I use the %p notation, c prints out as (nil). But why?

Comment: `c = &b;
` gives out a warning.